# What is this succulent, matted plant?

Tags: identification

What is this plant and how do I control it? It has smooth, teardrop-shaped,  succulent leaves branching from a succulent stem. It has small flowers with 5 white petals. It forms a thick, ground-hugging mat and is out-competing my bermuda lawn. I have ripped it up and it just comes back. I am near Blythe, California.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a portulaca of some sort. The same conditions beloved by your Bermuda Grass are also beloved by this plant. I am almost thinking you should *over water* your lawn...succulents are unable to deal with too much water. What are you doing for fertilizer? Have you tried any 'products' on the lawn up to this point?

Comment: I fertilized with simplot turf supreme (16.6.8 + 16% sulfur + 1.5% iron) and I just sprayed with Ortho Weed b gon.

Comment: Let's see what happens. ..when was the last time you applied fertilize?  Was it the same formula/brand?  If this Ortho Weed B Gon doesn't work, please do not use it again.  Warm season grasses are awful to manage.  The main maintenance practice you have to adhere to is regular fertilization, regular water, aeration once per year.  Healthy crop of bermuda should out compete this plant.  I love cool season grasses because the differences between grass needs and weed needs are easy to change.  Your grass itself is a weed, portulaca is an ornamental potting plant.  Will be back...

Comment: Please take a picture of the lawn NOW after you've sprayed this weed killer.  It should be showing signs of damage of weeds only...other people have destroyed their entire lawns using this product.  Perhaps never reading the directions?